# TextView with onTouchEvent

Tags: android, get, textview, element, touch-event

I have a problem with my custom TextView in a ListView. 
I override onTouchEvent but I don't found the way to get the element, un my case the object Tarea.
I need when the user slide to right with the onTouchEvent capture the id and text of this TextView (In a Listview).

This is my code:

```
public class TextViewFinger extends TextView {

float historicX = Float.NaN;
float historicY = Float.NaN;
static final float TRIGGER_DELTA = 150;

public TextViewFinger(Context context){
    super(context);
}
public TextViewFinger(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public TextViewFinger(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){

     switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            historicX = e.getX();
            historicY = e.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             if ((e.getX() - historicX) > TRIGGER_DELTA)  {
                 onSlideComplete(Direction.RIGHT);

                return false;
            } 
             else if ((e.getX() - historicX) < -TRIGGER_DELTA) {

                onSlideComplete(Direction.LEFT);
               return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(e);
        }
     return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}

enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT;

    }

 public void onSlideComplete(Direction dir){
     if(dir==Direction.RIGHT){
         this.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
         this.setText("Hecho" + ": " +  this.getText());

        // this.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left));
         //this.setTextColor(color.white);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Derecha", 1).show();
     }
     if(dir==Direction.LEFT){
         this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         this.setText("Borrar" + ": " +  this.getText());


         //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Izquierda", 1).show();
     }

    // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Derecha", 5).show();
 }

}



class TareasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tarea>{
private ArrayList<Tarea> tareas;

public TareasAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Tarea> objects) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.tareas=objects;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){
    View v = convertView;


    if (v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v= vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    Tarea t = tareas.get(position);
    if(t != null){
        TextView txtTarea= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNotaCustomID);

        txtTarea.setText(t.getTarea_description());
        txtTarea.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        txtTarea.setClickable(true);
        //txtTarea.setId((int) t.getId());
        txtTarea.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //int t= (Integer) v.getTag();

               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"f",4).show();


            }
        });
    }
    //LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //li.inflate(layout.list_item, null);

    return v;

}
public int getCount(){
    return tareas.size();
}
public Tarea getItem(int position){
    return this.tareas.get(position);

}
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}


}
```

And

```
 public class Tarea {

private int id;
private String tarea_description;
private Integer urgencia;

public double getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTarea_description() {
    return tarea_description;
}
public void setTarea_description(String tarea_description) {
    this.tarea_description = tarea_description;
}
public Integer getUrgencia() {
    return urgencia;
}
public void setUrgencia(Integer urgencia) {
    this.urgencia = urgencia;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance,
Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
int id = TextViewFlinger.this.getId();
```

from within your touch event?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. One way is to create an interface that defines two methods, say onRightSwipe() and onLeftSwipe(); you then provide this listener in your adapter (add a setter method to your TextView implementation) and call it when you detect a right/left swipe. But the best implementation depends on the specific use case too. You can model this sort of listener after one of Android's, for example the [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html).